# How do you get pexpect to trigger on process.expect("$") for the linux command line prompt?

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I am having issues with pexpect detecting `"$"` of the Linux command prompt. To give a better picture of what I am trying to accomplish:

Example Command Line prompt that I want to trigger my pexpect:

`testcomp@testcomp-desktop:~$`

Example of my pexpect code to detect it:

`child.expect(['$',pexpect.TIMEOUT])`

What results from this after testing it is that it chooses pexpect.TIMEOUT even though the prompt is there. I have also tried a couple of different variations of `"$"` like `"\$"` and `"~$"`

Comment: @Asocia if you can't expect it then is there any way to verify that the command prompt is printed?

Comment: First: `$` matches the end of a line when parsed as a regex; it doesn't match a dollar sign. `[$]` should work; whether `\$` does depends on what kind of string you put it in.

Comment: Second: We really need a [mre] to know if the prompt _should_ be seen. Please extend the code in your question to be a runnable example that *should* be able to match a prompt (maybe instantiate `child` by spawning something like `bash -l -i`)

Comment: @Charles Duffy, you were right the [$] expression does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI this is the code that should work if you want to do a console connection to a Linux machine (I was using minicom). What was described in the comments above was to use '[$]' to detect the Linux Command Line Prompt and it seemed to work well.

```
child = pexpect.spawn("minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0")
check = child.expect(["login",'[$]'])
if(check == 0):
    child.sendline(username)
    child.sendline(password)
else:
    child.sendline("\r")
```